# Creating a path from the edge of an image

Tags: javascript, image-processing, canvas

I have a binary image (e.g., .png) with background transparency. Let's say it looks like a blob with an irregular, but solid shape (no holes and it's all in one piece).

In JavaScript, I'd like to create a path that represents a bounding polygon. The polygon should be convex, but doesn't have to be. The output could simply be a list of coordinates:

`[0, 0], [0, 5], [7, 0]`

What are some good options? So far I've considered writing a [QuickHull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QuickHull) plugin in [Caman](http://camanjs.com/guides/#Extending), but that feels a little heavy duty. I've tagged this with `canvas` but only because it seemed like a good jumping-off point.

Comment: are you searching for an algorithmus to implement or for a JavaScript library which will do this?

Comment: That really depends on what libraries are available. I haven't seen any that will do this end to end. Surely pieces are implemented by various libraries but I'm looking for a strategy for using them, or not.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the "marching ants" algorithm to determine the outline path of a closed subsection of an image.

The marching ants algorithm creates a set of points representing an outline path.  Then you can use those points to draw a closed path around the subsection of your image.

The most important part of the algorithm is telling it what is/isn't part of your desired subsection.  Since you're wanting to include only non-transparent pixels on your image, you could define how to select pixels like this:

```
// This is used by the marching ants algorithm
// to determine the outline of the non-transparent
// pixels on the image
// The data[] array is the pixel array fetched by context.getImageData

var defineNonTransparent=function(x,y){
    var a=data[(y*cw+x)*4+3];
    return(a>20);
}
```

Here's annotated example code using the marching ants algorithm from D3: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/UyG6L/

[image][image][image]

This example uses .png  as the source image.  If you have a blob you will have to convert your blob to .png format.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

    // canvas related variables
    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    var cw=canvas.width;
    var ch=canvas.height;

    // checkbox to show/hide the original image
    var $showImage=$("#showImage");
    $showImage.prop('checked', true);

    // checkbox to show/hide the path outline
    var $showOutline=$("#showOutline");
    $showOutline.prop('checked', true);

    // an array of points that defines the outline path
    var points;

    // pixel data of this image for the defineNonTransparent 
    // function to use
    var imgData,data;

    // This is used by the marching ants algorithm
    // to determine the outline of the non-transparent
    // pixels on the image
    var defineNonTransparent=function(x,y){
        var a=data[(y*cw+x)*4+3];
        return(a>20);
    }

    // load the image
    var img=new Image();
    img.crossOrigin="anonymous";
    img.onload=function(){

        // draw the image
        // (this time to grab the image's pixel data
        ctx.drawImage(img,canvas.width/2-img.width/2,canvas.height/2-img.height/2);

        // grab the image's pixel data
        imgData=ctx.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        data=imgData.data;

        // call the marching ants algorithm
        // to get the outline path of the image
        // (outline=outside path of transparent pixels
        points=geom.contour(defineNonTransparent);

        ctx.strokeStyle="red";
        ctx.lineWidth=2;

        $showImage.change(function(){ redraw(); });

        $showOutline.change(function(){ redraw(); });

        redraw();

    }
    img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/sun.png";

    // redraw the canvas
    // user determines if original-image or outline path or both are visible
    function redraw(){

        // clear the canvas
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

        // draw the image
        if($showImage.is(':checked')){
            ctx.drawImage(img,canvas.width/2-img.width/2,canvas.height/2-img.height/2);
        }

        // draw the path (consisting of connected points)
        if($showOutline.is(':checked')){
            // draw outline path
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(points[0][0],points[0][4]);
            for(var i=1;i<points.length;i++){
                var point=points[i];
                ctx.lineTo(point[0],point[1]);
            }
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.stroke();
        }

    }


}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

<script>
// this is a "marching ants" algorithm used to calc the outline path
(function() {
    // d3-plugin for calculating outline paths
    // License: https://github.com/d3/d3-plugins/blob/master/LICENSE
    //
    // Copyright (c) 2012-2014, Michael Bostock
    // All rights reserved.
    //
    //  Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
    //  modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
    //* Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice, this
    //  list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
    //* Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice,
    //  this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation
    //  and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
    //* The name Michael Bostock may not be used to endorse or promote products
    //  derived from this software without specific prior written permission.
    // THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL MICHAEL BOSTOCK BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE. 
    geom = {}; 
    geom.contour = function(grid, start) { 
      var s = start || d3_geom_contourStart(grid), // starting point 
          c = [],    // contour polygon 
          x = s[0],  // current x position 
          y = s[1],  // current y position 
          dx = 0,    // next x direction 
          dy = 0,    // next y direction 
          pdx = NaN, // previous x direction 
          pdy = NaN, // previous y direction 
          i = 0; 

      do { 
        // determine marching squares index 
        i = 0; 
        if (grid(x-1, y-1)) i += 1; 
        if (grid(x,   y-1)) i += 2; 
        if (grid(x-1, y  )) i += 4; 
        if (grid(x,   y  )) i += 8; 

        // determine next direction 
        if (i === 6) { 
          dx = pdy === -1 ? -1 : 1; 
          dy = 0; 
        } else if (i === 9) { 
          dx = 0; 
          dy = pdx === 1 ? -1 : 1; 
        } else { 
          dx = d3_geom_contourDx[i]; 
          dy = d3_geom_contourDy[i]; 
        } 

        // update contour polygon 
        if (dx != pdx && dy != pdy) { 
          c.push([x, y]); 
          pdx = dx; 
          pdy = dy; 
        } 

        x += dx; 
        y += dy; 
      } while (s[0] != x || s[1] != y); 

      return c; 
    }; 

    // lookup tables for marching directions 
    var d3_geom_contourDx = [1, 0, 1, 1,-1, 0,-1, 1,0, 0,0,0,-1, 0,-1,NaN], 
        d3_geom_contourDy = [0,-1, 0, 0, 0,-1, 0, 0,1,-1,1,1, 0,-1, 0,NaN]; 

    function d3_geom_contourStart(grid) { 
      var x = 0, 
          y = 0; 

      // search for a starting point; begin at origin 
      // and proceed along outward-expanding diagonals 
      while (true) { 
        if (grid(x,y)) { 
          return [x,y]; 
        } 
        if (x === 0) { 
          x = y + 1; 
          y = 0; 
        } else { 
          x = x - 1; 
          y = y + 1; 
        } 
      } 
    } 

    })();
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="checkbox" id="showImage" />Show Image<br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="showOutline" />Show Outline Path<br>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=450></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

This is pure JS solution without depending on any 3rd party library.

```
function getOutline(ctx,pointX,pointY,w,h){
    var imageData = ctx.getImageData(pointX, pointY, w, h);
    var data = imageData.data;
    var outline=[];
    for(var x=0;x<w;x++){
        for(var y=0;y<h;y++){
            var index = (x + y * w) * 4;

            var nextIndex, lastIndex, leftIndex, rightIndex;
            nextIndex = (x + (y +1) * w ) * 4;
            lastIndex = (x + (y -1) * w ) * 4;
            leftIndex = index - 4;
            rightIndex = index + 4;

            var cx={"X":x,"Y":y}; 
            if(data[index+3] !== 0 && 
                ( (data[nextIndex+3] === 0)
                    || ( data[lastIndex+3] === 0)
                    || ( data[leftIndex+3] === 0)
                    || ( data[rightIndex+3] === 0) 
                )
            ){
                outline.push(cx);
            }
        }
    }
    return outline;
}
```

[Demo](https://github.com/amitguptagwl/web-snippets/tree/master/canvas)