# How can I get all coordinates of shape's edge in <canvas>?

Tags: html, canvas

There is a shape in my canvas, and I need to get all coordinates of its edge. The shape may be regular or irregular.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a path from the edge of an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23983461/creating-a-path-from-the-edge-of-an-image)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the "Marching Squares" algorithm to detect the edge path of a closed shape:

This one by Michael Bostock for his excellent d3 visualization tool is great:

https://github.com/d3/d3-plugins/tree/master/geom/contour

[image][image][image]

The key to using his version of Marching Squares is defining the function that defines pixels inside your shape vs pixels outside your shape.  Here's a function that uses the .getImageData pixel array (`data`) to fetch non-transparent pixels:

```
    // This is used by the marching ants algorithm
    // to determine the outline of the non-transparent
    // pixels on the image

    var defineNonTransparent=function(x,y){
        var a=data[(y*cw+x)*4+3];
        return(a>20);
    }
```

Example code and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/5v5hmo62/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

// Marching Squares Edge Detection
// this is a "marching ants" algorithm used to calc the outline path
(function() {
    // d3-plugin for calculating outline paths
    // License: https://github.com/d3/d3-plugins/blob/master/LICENSE
    //
    // Copyright (c) 2012-2014, Michael Bostock
    // All rights reserved.
    //
    //  Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
    //  modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
    //* Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice, this
    //  list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
    //* Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice,
    //  this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation
    //  and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
    //* The name Michael Bostock may not be used to endorse or promote products
    //  derived from this software without specific prior written permission.
    // THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL MICHAEL BOSTOCK BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE. 
    geom = {}; 
    geom.contour = function(grid, start) { 
      var s = start || d3_geom_contourStart(grid), // starting point 
          c = [],    // contour polygon 
          x = s[0],  // current x position 
          y = s[1],  // current y position 
          dx = 0,    // next x direction 
          dy = 0,    // next y direction 
          pdx = NaN, // previous x direction 
          pdy = NaN, // previous y direction 
          i = 0; 

      do { 
        // determine marching squares index 
        i = 0; 
        if (grid(x-1, y-1)) i += 1; 
        if (grid(x,   y-1)) i += 2; 
        if (grid(x-1, y  )) i += 4; 
        if (grid(x,   y  )) i += 8; 

        // determine next direction 
        if (i === 6) { 
          dx = pdy === -1 ? -1 : 1; 
          dy = 0; 
        } else if (i === 9) { 
          dx = 0; 
          dy = pdx === 1 ? -1 : 1; 
        } else { 
          dx = d3_geom_contourDx[i]; 
          dy = d3_geom_contourDy[i]; 
        } 

        // update contour polygon 
        if (dx != pdx && dy != pdy) { 
          c.push([x, y]); 
          pdx = dx; 
          pdy = dy; 
        } 

        x += dx; 
        y += dy; 
      } while (s[0] != x || s[1] != y); 

      return c; 
    }; 

    // lookup tables for marching directions 
    var d3_geom_contourDx = [1, 0, 1, 1,-1, 0,-1, 1,0, 0,0,0,-1, 0,-1,NaN], 
        d3_geom_contourDy = [0,-1, 0, 0, 0,-1, 0, 0,1,-1,1,1, 0,-1, 0,NaN]; 

    function d3_geom_contourStart(grid) { 
      var x = 0, 
          y = 0; 

      // search for a starting point; begin at origin 
      // and proceed along outward-expanding diagonals 
      while (true) { 
        if (grid(x,y)) { 
          return [x,y]; 
        } 
        if (x === 0) { 
          x = y + 1; 
          y = 0; 
        } else { 
          x = x - 1; 
          y = y + 1; 
        } 
      } 
    } 

    })();


    //////////////////////////////////////////

    // canvas related variables
    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    var cw=canvas.width;
    var ch=canvas.height;

    // checkbox to show/hide the original image
    var $showImage=$("#showImage");
    $showImage.prop('checked', true);

    // checkbox to show/hide the path outline
    var $showOutline=$("#showOutline");
    $showOutline.prop('checked', true);

    // an array of points that defines the outline path
    var points;

    // pixel data of this image for the defineNonTransparent 
    // function to use
    var imgData,data;

    // This is used by the marching ants algorithm
    // to determine the outline of the non-transparent
    // pixels on the image
    var defineNonTransparent=function(x,y){
        var a=data[(y*cw+x)*4+3];
        return(a>20);
    }

    // load the image
    var img=new Image();
    img.crossOrigin="anonymous";
    img.onload=function(){

        // draw the image
        // (this time to grab the image's pixel data
        ctx.drawImage(img,canvas.width/2-img.width/2,canvas.height/2-img.height/2);

        // grab the image's pixel data
        imgData=ctx.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        data=imgData.data;

        // call the marching ants algorithm
        // to get the outline path of the image
        // (outline=outside path of transparent pixels
        points=geom.contour(defineNonTransparent);

        ctx.strokeStyle="red";
        ctx.lineWidth=2;

        $showImage.change(function(){ redraw(); });

        $showOutline.change(function(){ redraw(); });

        redraw();

    }
    img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/sun.png";

    // redraw the canvas
    // user determines if original-image or outline path or both are visible
    function redraw(){

        // clear the canvas
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

        // draw the image
        if($showImage.is(':checked')){
            ctx.drawImage(img,canvas.width/2-img.width/2,canvas.height/2-img.height/2);
        }

        // draw the path (consisting of connected points)
        if($showOutline.is(':checked')){
            // draw outline path
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(points[0][0],points[0][1]);
            for(var i=1;i<points.length;i++){
                var point=points[i];
                ctx.lineTo(point[0],point[1]);
            }
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.stroke();
        }

    }

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="checkbox" id="showImage" />Show Image<br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="showOutline" />Show Outline Path<br>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=450></canvas>    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `points=geom.contour(defineNonTransparent)` it seems that the points is the result I need.